# Relation between subvarieties corresponding to union and intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

This may be a rather trivial question, but here goes:

I have been attempting to prove (for myself) that the Zariski topology is indeed a topology, i.e showing that the varieties of the affine space $A_\mathbb{K}^n$ do indeed behave as closed sets:

1) $A_\mathbb{K}^n$ and $\emptyset$ are varieties (which is easy)

2) If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are varieties then $V_1\cup V_2$ is a variety.

3)If $\{ V_\alpha \}_{\alpha\in \Lambda}$ is a collection of varieties, then $\underset{\alpha \in \Lambda}{\bigcap}V_\alpha$ is also a variety.

Now since $V=Z(S)$ for some $S\subseteq \mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]$ in order for $V$ to be a variety, the question is regarding how the zero-locus of a union and intersection should be. It seems rather simple to show that:

$Z(S_1)\cap Z(S_2)=Z(S_1\cdot S_2)$ and $Z(S_1)\cup Z(S_2)=Z(S_1+S_2)$

But is it also true that $\underset{\alpha \in \Lambda}{\bigcap}Z(S_\alpha)= Z \Big( \underset{\alpha \in \Lambda}{\bigcup} S_\alpha \Big)$ and $\underset{\alpha \in \Lambda}{\bigcup}Z(S_\alpha)= Z \Big( \underset{\alpha \in \Lambda}{\bigcap} S_\alpha \Big)$ ?

A second question I'm having is whether:

$Z\Big( (S_1)\Big) =  Z\Big( (S_2)\Big) $ if and only if $(S_1)=(S_2)$?

I would appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Why did you suddenly switch to union and intersection of the ideals? (Also, you are not showing that the unions and intersections are varieties, but that they are closed subsets).

Comment: regarding your second question, you may want to read into Hilbert's Nullstellensatz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz.

Comment: Second question : no, look at $(x)$ and $(x^2)$ in $k[x]$.

Comment: I switched to union and intersections for two reasons, I was wondering if the relation could be expressed strictly in set language, and second I was unsure as to how to express an inifinte (algebraic) product of sets.

Comment: strictly set language will not do, you have to consider sums of ideal. See my comment for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $Z(S_1)\cap Z(S_2)=Z(S_1\cdot S_2)$ and $Z(S_1)\cup Z(S_2)=Z(S_1+S_2)$

You got this wrong. If $f \in S_1 \cdot S_2$, this means that $f$ will vanish on *both* sets $Z(S_1)$ and $Z(S_2)$, because $f$ is in both ideals generated by $S_1$ and $S_2$. Thus $f$ will vanish on $Z(S_1) \cup Z(S_2)$. From this it is easy to see that $Z(S_1) \cup Z(S_2) = Z(S_1 \cdot S_2)$.

The same goes for the other case, if $f \in S_1 + S_2$, you only know that it will vanish, where both $S_1$ and $S_2$ vanish, i.e. $f$ vanishes on $Z(S_1)\cap Z(S_2)$. Now it should be easy to show that in fact, $Z(S_1) \cap Z(S_2) = Z(S_1 + S_2)$.

For the general case show that $\bigcap_\alpha Z(S_\alpha) = Z(\sum_\alpha S_\alpha)$.

> A second question I'm having is whether:
>   $Z\Big( (S_1)\Big) =  Z\Big( (S_2)\Big) $ if and only if $(S_1)=(S_2)$?

That is not true. In general we have $Z(S) = Z(\sqrt{S})$, where $\sqrt{S} = \{f \in k[x_1,\dots,x_n] \mid \exists n: f^n \in S \}$ is the so called *radical* of $S$. Try proving this identity, it's not hard and a good exercise.

So we see immediatly, that there might be different ideals which have the same zero locus. If $S \neq \sqrt{S}$ this is the case, which happens for example if $S = (x_1^2)$. Then $\sqrt{S} = (x_1)$.